# Hot water tank elements

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In a 2 element hot water tank, is there a kilowatt power usage increase if only one heating element is operating correctly?

Comment: This might be better asked on the Home Improvement SE. It certainly isn't 'fluid-dynamics'. As for the question, it depends on what the other heating element is doing (or not), and how the remaining one is aging.

Comment: The answer to this is dependent on how the circuits are designed.  I agree with @JonCuster, Home Improvement SE or Electrical Engineering SE will be better places for this question, and even then it will help to have a schematic of the circuits involved.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, I do apologize for my ignorance of "fluid-dynamics" And yes I may go to home improvement SE to ask. I just thought if I were to sign in to your site I might skip the layman like myself and get a solid friendly answer from scholars like yourself. Thank you, Jeff

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know how the power consumption will be affected by the loss of one element without first knowing the internal circuitry of the heater. In one of the simplest cases, the two elements are powered in parallel with only on-off regulation. In this case, the power during heating would be roughly half when operating with only one element. The time it takes to heat a given volume of water would be roughly twice as long.

Another question you might be interested in is: "Will there be an increase in energy consumption?" (because that's usually what we are billed for).

The same amount of energy (kilowatt-*hours*) would be required to heat a given volume of water whether one or two elements are used. Depending on the internal circuitry of the device, operating with only one element could introduce other inefficiencies that result in additional energy consumption, but in terms of physics, heating the water requires the same amount of energy.